# SQLite Database sometimes all tables get deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

My app has a SQLite database. I don't know how to explain, but sometimes all tables from the sqlite file gets deleted. It doesn't happen frequently but it happens. The .db file still exists but no tables.

## I use this code to open and get the .db from documents directory.

```
#pragma mark LOCAL DATABASE
-(void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Spread.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) {
        return;
    }
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Spread.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Spread - DB Created");
    }
}
+(FMDatabase *) getDatabase {
    static FMDatabase *db;
    if (!db) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Spread.sqlite"];
        FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];
        [db open];
        return db;
    } else {
        return db;
    }
}
```

Comment: If a DB file doesn't exist then SQLite will create one, so the presence of a file is proof of nothing.

Comment: You probably need to add more logs to the above code, to figure out what path it's going down.

Comment: We can't help you with an error that happens **sometimes**. Try to find a pattern, we need you to describe how to reproduce the problem. Otherwise your code looks fine.

Comment: @HotLicks I set a breakpoint and reviwed step by step. The problem ins't the .db file, it still exist. The tables that gets deleted.

Comment: @Merlevede I have been trying for weeks to find a pattern but i really can't explain it. What should I do?

Comment: The first routine you posted copies a presumably empty database based on some condition.  Perhaps it is getting called even if you already have a database - that could be 'wiping out your tables.'  Put a breakpoint in that routine and see how often and by whom it is called.

Comment: Problems that happen sometimes are the hardest to track, because we don't know what causes them. Just run your app and use it until the problem happens. Try to run it again and try to do interact with your app exactly the same way as the previous to see if it happens again.

Comment: May have nothing to do with it, but I'm curious why your first routine is an instance method, and the second a class method.

Comment: @OwenHartnett I just don't wanna create a lot of FMDatabase instances. Something wrong with that. The first is called on app opening. The second everytime I want to update or query something.

Comment: Are the tables already defined in the DB that's packaged in the bundle?

Comment: @HotLicks Yes sir, do you suggest changing that? Even if the db can restore all tables, they are going to be empty anyway. My app should be able to recover from a empty db?

Comment: I'm more concerned with how often your first method is called.

Comment: @OwenHartnett On the app launch ONLY

Comment: I wanted to know if the tables were in the bundle DB to know if it was deleting the tables.

Comment: Do you notice this problem only immediately after installing, or after the app has been used for several start/end cycles?  Is the symptom always apparent immediately on startup, or does it appear after you've been actively using the app for awhile?  Do you create/delete any other files in the application?

Comment: i have the same problem my data base table get deleted every time when i run my app.